# date-fns-tz to work on IE11, is there any alternative to date-time-format-timezone polyfill?

Tags: node.js, timezone, internet-explorer-11

I am using zonedTimeToUtc function from 'date-fns-tz' in my react node project. inorder for that to support IE11, i saw an option to import date-time-format-timezone. That solution is working, but the package is large. So I would like to know if there is any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer (including IE11) doesn't have any built-in support for time zones other than that of the local computer and UTC.  Therefore, if you need to support IE then you will need to use the polyfill.